# Create a 2-column List using a variable for list name

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Because the original post ([Create List with name from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156711/create-list-with-name-from-variable-c-sharp)) was so old, I didn't want to approach this as an answer.

But, I wanted to add this use of the above solution because it was non-obvious to me. And, it may help some of my fellow noobs... Also, I ran into some issues I don't know how to address.

I needed a way to create a list using a variable name, in this case "mstrClock", for timing diagrams.

I was not able to get .NET to accept a two-column list, though, so I ended up with two dictionaries.

**Is there a way to structure this so that I can use a single dictionary for both columns?**

```
dictD.Add("mstrClock", new List<double>());
dictL.Add("mstrClock", new List<string>());
```

Then as I develop the timing diagram, I add to the lists as follows:

```
dictD["mstrClock"].Add(x);  // This value will normally be the time value.
dictL["mstrClock"].Add("L");    // This value will be the "L", "F" or "H" logic level
```

Then to get at the data I did this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < dictD["mstrClock"].Count; n++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(dictL["mstrClock"][n] + "\t" + dictD["mstrClock"][n].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store what you want to display, in the dictionary?

```
dict.Add("mstrClock", new List<string>());
dict["mstrClock"].Add($"L\t{x}"); 

for (int n = 0; n < dict["mstrClock"].Count; n++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(dict["mstrClock"][n]);
}
```

On another point, do you even need a dictionary?  What is the point of having a dictionary with one key?  If you only need a `List<string>`, then only create that.

```
var items = new List<string>());
items.Add($"L\t{x}"); 

foreach (var item in items)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: [Why not just store what you want to display, in the dictionary?]
Because I will need to add additional lists (Components) to the dictionary. For instance. mstrClock will be used to drive a 7490 four bit counter, which will then drive a 4-16 decoder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) in modern C# to create your two-column list as follows:

```
var list = new List<(double time, string logicLevel)>();
list.Add((1, "L"));
list.Add((2, "F"));

foreach (var element in list)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add($"{element.time} \t {element.logicLevel}");
}
```

If using a dictionary is a must, you can change the above code to something like:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<(double time, string logicLevel)>>();

dict["mstrClock"] = new List<(double time, string logicLevel)>();
dict["mstrClock"].Add((1, "L"));
dict["mstrClock"].Add((2, "F"));

var list = dict["mstrClock"];
foreach (var element in list)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add($"{element.time} \t {element.logicLevel}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to creating a 2-column list would be to create a list of [key/value pairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<double, string>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, string>(1, "L");

foreach (KeyValuePair<double, string> element in list)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add($"{element.key} \t {element.value}");
}
```